# How to crop the image using UIBezierPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibezierpath

I want to get the image from the `UIBezierpath` closed path(See the image). I draw the image on the `UIView` using `drawRect` method and also draw the lines are using the `drawRect` method. 
How can I get the particular closed path image? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This code used for draw the bezierpath.

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
for (NSString *pointString in pointArray) {
    if ([pointArray indexOfObject:pointString] == 0)
        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
    else
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
}
[aPath closePath];
```

[image]

Comment: How can we draw a line on the UIImageView, when i try to draw a line on the UIview is working but in uiimageview is not working could you help me please

Comment: mani did you achive your objective?

Comment: hi can you answer your own question....

Comment: @Rajneesh071 [Yup.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Please let me know if you found the solution. I'm also working with a similar functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643161/crop-image-in-swift

Answer (score 15):

You can use a `shapeLayer` for that. Something like,

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
for (NSString *pointString in pointArray) {
    if ([pointArray indexOfObject:pointString] == 0)
        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
    else
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
}
[aPath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
[view.layer setMask:shapeLayer];//or make it as [imageview.layer setMask:shapeLayer]; 
//and add imageView as subview of whichever view you want. draw the original image
//on the imageview in that case
```

To get it as an image,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`image` should have the corresponding image.

Comment: Thank you ACB...How to get the image from the UIBezierpath.

Comment: Thank you...I tried this, Its get the image and background is white color. I want image of the UIBezierPath portion(see imag cat head) only. Are you understand me?

Comment: Why dont you try to set the original image in UIImageView and use the above code on that. Check if that is giving the proper image. Instead of 'view' in code use 'imageview'.

Comment: My problem is after crop the image then chage to black & white image at the time. Image remaining background is black color. So I am searching particular path of the image.

Comment: @ACB can you send me sample of your code, because we are not getting proper image

Comment: Super-old but still helpful. Rendering it directly in an imageview does indeed remove the background.

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift** try this : [ZImageCropper](https://github.com/ZaidPathan/ZImageCropper)

ZImageCropper is using following things as core part:

- UIBezierPath
- UITouch Events
- CAShapeLayer
- CoreGraphics

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a couple of things that you have to take in notice.

1. Are you passing your UIImageView instead of your UIView?
2. If you are, did you enable your image view for touch handling?
3. Subclass your UIImageView and use `drawrect()` for handling that stuff for you.

If you want only a portion of the image (like the cat), then you need to submask your image according to UIBezierPath.

**Updated**

The following is a complete working example, change it to your requirements.

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  UIBezierPath *aPath;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *pathArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *dic;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()
 - (IBAction)Crop:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize pathArray,dic,imgView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];

 }
 - (void) setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath : (UIImageView *)imgView;
{

    NSLog(@"Mask Paths %@",clippingPath);

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.imgView.frame;
    maskLayer.path = [clippingPath CGPath];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];


    self.imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer;



}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

   UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   self->aPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
   [aPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:imgView]];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

  UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
  [aPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:imgView
                       ]];

 }
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

 }
- (IBAction)Crop:(id)sender
 {
  [self setClippingPath:aPath :imgView];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, now how do we save this layer as a uiimage with clear background? I tried converting CALayer self.imgView.layer.mask to a UIImage as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk . But it is not the desired result.

Comment: Hi umer sufyan. How do I start to understand uibezierpath? I tried to read the documentation but as I'm just a newbie, I am finding a hard time to get a grip. Please guide me to some good tutorials of uibezierpath. Thanks.

Comment: its bit late, but you should render your layer some where in and get desired UIImage..

Answer (score 2):

use this pod [ios-helpers](https://github.com/eleven-huang/ios-helpers#uibezierpathimage)

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithStrokeColor: (UIColor *)stroke_color andFillColor: (UIColor *)fill_color {

    // adjust bounds to account for extra space needed for lineWidth
    CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width + self.lineWidth * 2;
    CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height + self.lineWidth * 2;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, width, height);

    // create a view to draw the path in
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];

    // begin graphics context for drawing
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    // configure the view to render in the graphics context
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // get reference to the graphics context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // reverse the y-axis to match the opengl coordinate space
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -view.bounds.size.height);

    // translate matrix so that path will be centered in bounds
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(bounds.origin.x - self.lineWidth), -(bounds.origin.y - self.lineWidth));

    // stroke color
    [stroke_color setStroke];
    [self stroke];

    //fill color
    [fill_color setFill];
    [self fill];

    // get an image of the graphics context
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // end the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? It's good that you included a link to the docs and example code, but could you describe what exactly it does?

Answer (score 1):

If you're drawing everything in code just use -`addClip`, i.e.:

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
for (NSString *pointString in pointArray) {
    if ([pointArray indexOfObject:pointString] == 0)
        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
    else
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
}
[aPath closePath];


CGContextSaveGState(context);
{
    [aPath addClip];
    // draw image
    [aPath stroke];
}
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Hi hypercrypt...Thank you for your reply.

Comment: How to get the image from the particular UIBezierPath.

Comment: Create an image context and use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

Comment: Thank you. I want particular portion of the image(see imag cat head).

Answer (score 1):

iDev's answer is excellent, but if you need transparent background, then except 
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);`
you should use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
```

By default image context is created with opaque == YES, so you have to change it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me...

```
UIBezierPath *path = ....//your path
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef    context    = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, 8, 4*frame.size.width, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);

[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This Work 100%
```

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

```
mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
megView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lastPoint.x , lastPoint.y , k_POINT_WIDTH , k_POINT_WIDTH )];
//[megView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b_image22.png"]];
[megView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
megView.alpha = 2;
//megView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
//megView.layer.cornerRadius = megView.frame.size.width / 2;
megView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.main_uiview addSubview:megView];


self.bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[self.bezierPath moveToPoint:lastPoint];
```

}

```
  // Touchmove method


 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = YES;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.main_uiview.frame.size);
[self.bg_imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.main_uiview.frame.size.width, self.main_uiview.frame.size.height)];
megView.frame = CGRectMake( currentPoint.x - k_POINT_WIDTH/2 , currentPoint.y - k_POINT_WIDTH/2 , k_POINT_WIDTH , k_POINT_WIDTH );
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red,green ,blue, 0.20);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
  self.bg_imageview.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  [self.bg_imageview setAlpha:opacity];

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 lastPoint = currentPoint;

[self.bezierPath addLineToPoint:lastPoint];
```

}

```
 // TouchEnd Method


   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

```
[megView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

```
      // Image Crop Method


    -(UIImage *)croppedImage
   {
UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.bezierPath closePath];
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
_b_image = self.bg_imageview.image;
CGSize imageSize = _b_image.size;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self.bezierPath addClip];
[_b_image drawInRect:imageRect];

UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return croppedImage;
```

}