# Set size of UIView based on content size

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cashapelayer, contentsize

Is it possible to draw something on a `UIView`, then, after the drawing is completed, resize the view to be the same size as the thing that was previously drawn?

For example, if I draw a circle on a `UIView`, I would like to crop the `UIView` to the dimensions of the circle that I just drew on the view.

**UPDATE**

I am looking into using a CAShapeLayer as a possible solution.  Does anyone know how to convert a UIBezierPath to a CAShapeLayer then set the position of the CAShapeLayer?

I have tried:

```
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

but this does not work.

Comment: i guess what you are looking for is [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153223/how-to-crop-the-image-using-uibezierpath) check it, it might be helpful, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Have a look at this example that will answer both your questions.

First of all you need to add a `UIView` called *myView* and attach it to an `IBOutlet` ivar.

Define this global values for demonstration purposes:

```
#define POSITION    CGPointMake(50.0,50.0)
#define SIZE        CGSizeMake(100.0,100.0)
```

Declare two methods, one that will draw a shape in *myView* and another one that will resize the view to adapt it to the drawn shape:

```
-(void) circle
{
    CAShapeLayer *layerData = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layerData.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    UIBezierPath * dataPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, SIZE.width, SIZE.height)];

    layerData.path = dataPath.CGPath;
    layerData.position = CGPointMake(POSITION.x, POSITION.y);

    [myView.layer addSublayer:layerData];
}

-(void) resize
{
    ((CAShapeLayer *)[myView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0]).position = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(POSITION.x + myView.frame.origin.x , POSITION.y + myView.frame.origin.y, SIZE.width, SIZE.height);
}
```

Finally, in `viewWillAppear:` call both methods:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self circle];
    [self resize];
}
```

You can run the same code calling only *circle* and calling both methods. In both cases the drawn circle will be at the same exact position but in the second case *myView* has been resized to have the same size as the drawn shape.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow!  It worked. I have been trying to figure this our for days!  Thank you very much!

Comment: what about the case that you do not know where the UIBezierPath is being drawn?  It is not visible when the layer is displayed.

Comment: It is only a matter of getting the position and size of both your path and your view. I don't know exactly the context of your question but you either will have a `UIBezierPath` instance, or a `UIView` to get the path from (like the first line in the *resize* method). In both cases you have all the needed data to do what you are asking for.