# How Can I draw shapes on a UIImageView that's in my main view? getting invalid context error?

Tags: ios, drawrect, cgcontext

In my main view I have a user-defined class drawSquare that is a subclass of UIImageView.  In drawSquare.m I have the normal drawRect method shown below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    redSquare = CGRectMake(2,2,30,34);
    CGContextAddRect(context, redSquare);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

In my main view controller I have an object named word1Area of type drawSquare as an IBOutlet.
In my viewDidLoad method of my main view controller I have the lines:

```
[self.view addSubview:word1Area];
[word1Area drawRect:word1Area.frame];
```

I get an "invalid context" run time error. I have tried other variations of calling the drawRect method but keep getting the same error.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153223/how-to-crop-the-image-using-uibezierpath/15353848#15353848

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call drawRect yourself - you can tell the view `setNeedsDisplay`.