# UIImageView sides and top rounded borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Hi all I need to realize borders around an `UIImageView` like these.

Left, top and right border like an half-moon

http://imageshack.com/a/img841/3269/o90p.png

How can i do it ?

Comment: This one should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153223/how-to-crop-the-image-using-uibezierpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Create a `CAShapeLayer`
2. Set its path to be a `CGPathRef` based on `view.bounds` but with only two rounded corners (probably by using `[UIBezierPath
   bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]`)
3. Set your view.layer.mask to be the `CAShapeLayer`

Just take in account that this have a bad effect on performance.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

You can user `CALayer` for the same.

```
CALayer *l = [_btn layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:8.0];
```

and add `QuartzCore.framework`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to subclass `UIView` and override the `drawRect:` method. Then place add your image view as a subview. Your `drawRect:` method would look something like this (with `clipsToBounds` set to `YES`):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
    float borderWidth = 2.0f;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, borderWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, borderColor.CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect), rect.size.height/2, 2*M_PI, M_PI, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Alternatively you can look into masking with a semicircle image or creating a `CAShapeLayer` for the image view.