# Crop image in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext, image-masking

I am trying to crop image in swift. I'm trying to implement something like, user will capture a photo. Once photo is captured user will be allowed to set the crop area. I'm able to get the image from that crop area, but I want that the crop image should be resized to particular width and height. That is, if particular height or width is smaller then it should be resized.

[image]

This image should be of frame of it's maximum width and height. Currently it is just adding transparency to the other area.

I had also added my code for cropping

```html
            let tempLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            tempLayer.frame = self.view.frame
            
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            var endPoint: CGPoint!
            
            for (var i = 0; i<4; i++){
                let tag = 101+i
                let pointView = viewCrop.viewWithTag(tag)
                switch (pointView!.tag){
                case 101:
                    endPoint = CGPointMake(pointView!.center.x-20, pointView!.center.y-20)
                    path.moveToPoint(endPoint)
                default:
                    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(pointView!.center.x-20, pointView!.center.y-20))
                }
            }
            
            path.addLineToPoint(endPoint)
            path.closePath()
            tempLayer.path = path.CGPath
            
            tempLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            tempLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            imgReceiptView.layer.mask = tempLayer
            
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewCrop.bounds.size, imgReceiptView.opaque, 0.0);
            imgReceiptView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
            let cropImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cropImg, nil, nil, nil)
            imgReceiptView.hidden = true
            
            let tempImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(20,self.view.center.y-80, self.view.frame.width-40,160))
            tempImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            tempImageView.image = cropImg
            tempImageView.tag = 1001
            tempImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.view.addSubview(tempImageView)
```

Any help will be appreciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Use this Library to crop image as User Specific

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor

Thanks
Hope this will help you!