# Cutting a UIImageView according to UIBezier?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I have a `UIImageView`, with a certain image.
I also have a `UIBezierPath` in some strange shape.
I would like to cut the image to that shape and return a new image in that shape.

[image]

In the form of :

```
func getCut(bezier:UIBezierPath, image:UIImageView)->UIImageView
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mask` to do so. Here's a quick example.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var path: UIBezierPath!
    var touchPoint: CGPoint!
    var startPoint: CGPoint!

    var imageView =  UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0715"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            startPoint = touch.location(in: view)
            path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: startPoint)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            touchPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        }

        path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        startPoint = touchPoint

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        cut()
    }

    private func cut() {
        guard let path = path else { return }
        imageView = imageView.getCut(with: path)
    }

}

extension UIImageView {
    func getCut(with bezier: UIBezierPath) -> UIImageView {

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezier.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer to make an image with a clipping path.  Here is a Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let imageToCrop = UIImage(named: "test.jpg")!
let size = imageToCrop.size
let cutImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { imageContext in
    let context = imageContext.cgContext
    let clippingPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)).cgPath
    context.addPath(clippingPath)
    context.clip(using: .evenOdd)
    imageToCrop.draw(at: .zero)
}

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
imageView.image = cutImage
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAShapeLayer` for shaping the image... & then to get Image from that shape ...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.bounds.size);
[imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mainImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thank You...

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187507/5750652)..

Comment: Thanks, but this is not swift and not an answer to my question at all.

Comment: @Curnelious if this answer is okay with the equation approach then the approach is same just convert the code to swift..